# difference between phpmyadmin and php PDO

Tags: mysql, php

I'm running a query in Phpmyadmin and also execute the same query with php PDO but results are not equal. What could be wrong ? 
This is query :

```
SELECT dim_date_key as date ,dim_jdate_key as jdate, SUM(val_call_counts) as count
FROM `fact_j_service_location_table_ts` 
WHERE `dim_time_stamp` >= '1426451400'
AND `dim_time_stamp` < '1427311800' 
AND dim_service_id  = 2  
GROUP BY dim_date_key  
LIMIT 0,10;
```

phpmyadmin :

```
date        jdate       count   
20150316    13931225    5711    
20150317    13931226    6170    
20150318    13931227    7244    
20150319    13931228    7825    
20150320    13931229    6261    
20150321    13940101    4622    
20150322    13940102    4513    
20150323    13940103    4671
```

but php returns :

```
20150316    13931225    6295    
20150317    13931226    6170    
20150318    13931227    7244    
20150319    13931228    14170   
20150320    13931229    6261    
20150321    13940101    4622    
20150322    13940102    16879   
20150323    13940103    4671
```

Comment: Do you get the same results if you remove the LIMIT clause?

Comment: @MichaelGreen Yes, I've removed limit ,but results didn't change.

Comment: Try using an ORDER BY (same for each query).

Comment: What happens if you remove the jdate column from the SELECT list?